# Burning rectifier capacitor 220V input

Tags: rectifier

I have built the following circuit for 1 watt power LED lamp. The capacitor C4 (220uf 50v) was heating after a few seconds then it burnt. What is wrong with the circuit? I can remove C4 but reducing brightness.

[image]

Comment: Check what you had for R3 and ZD. These are rather important for regulating the voltage across C4.

Comment: I was used 1/4 watt 100 hom. But it burn , So I replaced with 1 watt 500 hom.

Comment: ZD is 4.7V 1 watt.

Comment: I have doubt, What power use this circuit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arshid - Your circuit will work as shown, but there are some problems.

First - why did the cap blow up? My best guess is that you installed it backwards. Look closely at C4 on the schematic. See the + sign? You need to pay attention to it. Your cap should have a polarity indicator, either a + or -.

I've simulated the circuit, and it should work. The maximum voltage across C4 is about 25 volts. The zener will dissipate about .75 watts, so be sure to use a 1-watt diode.

R3 NEEDS to be a 5-watt resistor. If you had not turned off the circuit after the cap blew, and you are using something like a 1/4 watt resistor, you would have seen R3 start smoking.

C5, for what it's worth, can be a 10-volt cap. Note that it filters the output of a 4.7 volt zener.

The current through the LED is about 100 mA.

Now for some suggestions. The first, and most important, is that you buy a cheap multimeter. Without it you will have no idea what's actually going on in your circuit.

Second, and very nearly as important - Never use a circuit that is powered directly from mains. It only takes a seconds carelessness making a measurement to cause you great bodily harm.

Third, (and this follows directly from the second) - get a transformer. And you don't need a big, expensive transformer. For what you are doing, 12 volts at one amp will do just fine. Your circuit can be replaced by

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojprY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But note that the LM317 needs to have a heat sink. The current set resistor R1 can be a 1/4 watt. The 470 uF cap will need to have the + end at the top, - end tied to ground.

Comment: Thanks .. But I can not simulating circuit.

Comment: I just want to say that the original circuit scares me.  (I would have put your second warning right at the top.)

Comment: @ArshidKK - I'm not asking you to. I'm just saying that if you replace C4 (paying attention to the orientation) and make sure R3 is a 5-watt resistor, the circuit should work.

Comment: Also, by my simulation, you can remove the zener completely.

Comment: Thanks .. But reducing brightness ..

Comment: Is it increase power wastage , when I using 5 watt or 1 watt resistor ?

Comment: No. The power dissipated will be the same regardless of watt rating. But a 1 watt resistor will only handle one watt safely - it gets hot. A 5-watt resistor will handle 5 watts. A 1-watt resistor that tries to dissipate 5 watts will get too hot and self-destruct.  And there is no way removing the zener will decrease brightness. It might have no effect, but it will not reduce output.

Answer (score 2):

C1, C2 and C3 are shown on the circuit as 105K and this likely means they are 1uF capacitors. Three in parallel and at 50Hz means an impedance of about 1061 ohms. This is the problem because from a 230V AC supply there will be a current taken of about 212 mA.

The 212mA is calculated very roughly by subtracting about 5V (zener and forward diode drops in bridge) from 230VAC and dividing by 1061 ohms.

This will flow thru R3 (rated at 100 ohms) and will dissipate a power of about 4.5 watts just in that resistor. Then, the resistor will die and go open circuit and no longer will 212mA flow but, the voltage across C4 will rise to something around peak mains voltage of over 300 volts - this will kill the 50 volt rated capacitor dead.

I believe C1-3 are far too high in value and you should try using 100nF capacitors.

Comment: Can I use 100nf capacitor for drive 1 watt LED?

Comment: Can I drive more LEDs without transformer (using 230 v AC supply)?   [ LED 1 watt, 3.6V and minimum 3mA]

Comment: With 3x 100nF capacitors, the current will be 21mA and about 1.5x this will be the maximum LED current. I don't know your LED spec so I can't tell you - I'm telling you why the circuit destroyed itself as per the question "What is wrong with the circuit?" asked by you.

Comment: My LED is 1 watt power LED. LED needs minimum 300mA for working.

Comment: Can I build LED lamp (with more LED) by changing ZD ?

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't going to work with the components shown on your circuit - whoever drew the circuit is wrong - where did it come from? The 10 ohm in series with the LED will drop 3V at 300mA leaving only 1.7 volts to power the LED but most white LEDs I've seen need much more voltage.

Comment: Think about the 100 ohm resistors with 300mA flowing - that's a power of 9 watts in each resistor - you might as well get a transformer for the size of both 100 ohm resistors AND it'll be much safer. Sorry but the circuit is crappy.

Comment: 10 hom resistor for protect LED. (The circuit is working ,if I remove C4. But low brightness)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can I use any other circuit for making LED lamp without transformer ?

Comment: Use an off-line switching regulator circuit but it will probably use a small transformer in order to generate the power into the LED. Also try Linear Technology - they may have something.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ... Transformer cost and size is high.